# How to have shaded grid entries

Tags: formatting, grid-layouts

Teaching a unit on log scales for a high school math class.

I saw this table on the internet.

[image: table]

I know how to colour individual grid entries, is there a nice way to incrementally colour them like the sample image?

Here is a simple command line to create a bare bones table....  I'm looking to colour the entries as they are in the image  (to accentuate the idea of "danger" to "okay")

```
Grid[{
  {"Environmental\nNoise", "Decibel\n  level"}, 
  {"Jet aircraft, 50 m away", "140"}, 
  {"Threshold of pain", "130"},
  {"Threshold of discomfort", "120"},
  {"Chainsaw, 1 m distance", "110"},
  {"Disco, 1 m from speaker", "100"},
  {"Diesel Truck, 10 m away", "90"}, 
  {"Kerbside of busy road, 5 m away", "80"},
  {"Vacuum, 1 m away", "70"},
  {"Conversational speech, 1 m", "60"},
  {"Average home", "50"},
  {"Quiet library", "40"},
  {"Quiet bedroom at night", "30"},
  {"Background in TV studio", "20"},
  {"Rustling leaves in the distance", "10"},
  {"Hearing threshold", "0"}}, Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {Automatic, Automatic, {{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> LightGray}, 
 Alignment -> Left]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Background -> {None, Prepend[Table[Hue[(k - 2)/35], {k, 15}], White]}
```

[image]

*Pedagogical word of caution*: this might not be the best example to give to grade-school students, as the bottom entry has a decibel level of zero; this may naturally lead students to think that the minimum possible decibel level is zero, which is false. Including examples of sounds with decibel levels below 0 might help to ensure this misconception dies in the crib.

Alternate:

```
Background -> {None, None, 
  Join[{{1, 1} -> LightGray, {1, 2} -> LightGray}, 
   Table[{k + 1, 2} -> Hue[(k - 2)/35], {k, 15}]]}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks fantastic, and simple to implement!

Comment: I appreciate the pedagogical note,  that IS important.   Sadly,  those kinds of subtle nuances are lost on about 99% of my students (pardon my cynicism!)  I'm happy if they actually understand a dB is a tenth of a Bel!

Answer (score 3):

With `data` being your input text:

```
col = With[{l = Length[Last /@ data[[2 ;;]]]}, 
  Table[Blend[{Red, Yellow, Green}, x],{x, 0, 1, 1/(l - 1)}]];
Grid[data, Frame -> All, 
 Background -> {None, None, 
   Join[{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}} -> LightGray}, 
    Rule @@@ Thread@{{#, 2} & /@ Range[2, Length@data], col}]}, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Or with `Blend[{Green, Blue, Red}, x]`:

[image]

or simply with `ColorData["Rainbow"][x]`:

[image]